# Refraction methods don't agree with each other - or Snell's law

Tags: c++, eigen, raytracing

I have been trying to put together a refraction method that takes in Eigen::Vector3d's for the ray and the normal of the surface, as well as the index of refraction before and after the interface.

It needs to handle arbitrary surface normals, incident rays and indices of refraction. It does NOT need to handle total internal reflection, I can detect that outside the method and avoid it.

I have two, but they disagree and neither seem to match Snell's law. I think that both of these may have initially assumed that one side of the interface was always air, which is *not true* in my case.

The first implementation is from here: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/introduction-to-shading/reflection-refraction-fresnel

And it is:

```
Eigen::Vector3d refract(
  const Eigen::Vector3d &incVector, 
  Eigen::Vector3d surfaceNormal, 
  double etai, 
  double etat )
{
  Eigen::Vector3d incidentVector = incVector.normalized();
  double cosTheta = std::clamp( incidentVector.dot( surfaceNormal ), -1.0, 1.0 );

  if ( cosTheta < 0.0 ) {
    cosTheta = -cosTheta;
  } else {
    std::swap( etai, etat );
    surfaceNormal = -surfaceNormal;
  }

  double eta = etai / etat;

  Eigen::Vector3d newVector;
  double k = 1 - eta * eta * ( 1 - cosTheta * cosTheta );

  if ( k < 0 ) {
    // Total internal reflection, not handled ATM
    // Prefer to detect this outside?
    newVector = incidentVector;
    //fprintf(stderr, "total internal reflection, ignore\n");
  } else {
    newVector = eta * incidentVector + ( eta * cosTheta - std::sqrt( k ) ) * surfaceNormal;
    //fprintf(stderr, "good data:\n");
  }

  return newVector;
}
```

The second implementation is from here: [https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html#dielectrics/snell'slaw](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html#dielectrics/snell%27slaw)

And it is:

```
Eigen::Vector3d refract2(
  const Eigen::Vector3d &incVector, 
  Eigen::Vector3d surfaceNormal, 
  double etai, 
  double etat )
{
  Eigen::Vector3d incidentVector = incVector.normalized();

  double eta = etai / etat;
  double cosTheta = std::min( ( -incidentVector ).dot( surfaceNormal ), 1.0 );
  Eigen::Vector3d rOutPerpendicular = eta * ( incidentVector + cosTheta * surfaceNormal );
  double rOutPerpSq = std::pow( rOutPerpendicular.norm(), 2 );
  Eigen::Vector3d rOutParallel = -std::sqrt( std::abs( 1.0 - rOutPerpSq ) ) * surfaceNormal; 
  Eigen::Vector3d newVector = rOutPerpendicular + rOutParallel; 
  newVector.normalize(); // unsure if needed

  return newVector;
}
```

(To be clear, for now while testing I only look at the results when total internal reflection is not occurring, so I'm not comparing junk data)

**Failing example:**

Incident ray: {0.18942838831751452, 0.013336588641010838, -0.62199774163029875}

Normal: {-0.27689443647572254, -0.47422711874752033, 0.13779107028412740}

First IOR: 1.6393627735221412

Second IOR: 1.9297769096957305

1st method results: {0.35033145873009269, 0.19363689493923739, -0.86368789659903644}

2nd method results: {0.37149016792865353, 0.21243159055249269, -0.90380743218214299}

These are close, but not the same.

As well, they don't seem to agree with Snell's law, if I understand it correctly:

IOR1/IOR2 = 0.84950895892967282

sin(dot product(refracted, normal) / sin(dot product(incident, normal) = 2.1044755362563823

sin(dot product(refracted, normal) / sin(dot product(incident, normal) = 2.2383953074347627

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: https://vertexwahn.de/2020/12/19/refraction/

Comment: @Vertexwahn That method seems to agree with #2. I must be doing something wrong with my test though, as the result still doesn't seem right. The ratio of sin(dot product(refracted, normal) / sin(dot product(incident, normal) should be equal to etai/etat, shouldn't it? Am I missing something there?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was doing my testing wrong.

The dot product = cos(angle). So you first have to remove the cos with arc-cos.

IE, the following test passes:

```
    double cosThetaIncident = incident.dot( normal );
    double thetaIncident = std::acos( cosThetaIncident );
    double sinThetaIncident = std::sin(thetaIncident);

    double cosThetaRefracted = refracted.dot( normal );
    double thetaRefracted = std::acos( cosThetaRefracted );
    double sinThetaRefracted = std::sin(thetaRefracted);
```

In this case, `sinThetaRefracted / sinThetaIncident ) == ( startIOR / endinIOR )`

(Within floating point tolerances, and assuming we are not in a total internal reflection case)

**Update:**

I've learned a bit more. Most refract() methods seem to assume something about the orientation of the surface being hit. In that, some choose to have -incidentVector used in the calculation like the one from vertexwahn.de.

By removing the negative sign and adding in the correction, I no longer see flips along the axis when refraction occurs.

Comment: Assuming normal and incident are unit vectors, the cos() you quote is correct.  For production code, anytime I see arc sin/cos values, I would step back and be sure you are not doing something wrong as they are expensive to calculate and often point to an error in the algorithm itself.

Comment: This acos and sin are only used in a unit test, not in the calculation of the refraction itself.